# ListHeaderComponent receives object, expected a string or class/function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render a `FlatList` component with a `ListHeaderComponent` prop,  The FlatList renders fine without that prop, but when I add ListHeaderComponent I get the following error.[image]

Here's the `render()` function of the Discover class:

```
render() {
  renderFlatListItem = (event) => {
    return (
      <Event
        description={event.Description}
        startTime={event.StartTimeToString}
        Location={event.Location ? event.Location : 'TBD' }
        key={event.ID}
      />
    )
  }
  ListHeaderCreate = () => {
    return (
      <DiscoverSearch
        resultDescription={this.state.popularEvents ? 'Popular Events': 
        'Search Results'}
        categories={this.state.categories}
        passCategory={this.handleSelectedCategory}
        passInitialPosition={this.handleInitialPosition}
        passLastPosition={this.handleLastPosition}
        passSearch={this.handleSearch}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
      ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderCreate()}
        data={this.state.events}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          renderFlatListItem(item)
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is the `render()` function of the DiscoverSearch class:

```
render () {
  const pickerItems = this.props.categories.map((category) => {
  <Picker.Item key={category.ID} label={category.Name} value={category.ID}/>
  });
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Search Events"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({searchText: text})}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Location"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({LocationText: text})}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
      <Picker
        onValueChange={(category) => this.props.passCategory}
      >
      {pickerItems}
      </Picker>
      <Button
       title='Search'
       onPress={console.log(this.state)}
      />
      </View>
    </View>
   )
 }
```

I assume that the VirtualizedList must be a child of the flatList that I am importing from react-native, Should I be directing this question to the react-native repo on github? I can't find where my mistake is. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your DiscoverSearch class the categories map function opens up brackets but never returns anything. You need a return statement if you open up a block in a fat arrow function.

Comment: When modifying `pickerItems` to look like this: ` const pickerItems = this.props.categories.map((category) => { return(
      <Picker.Item key={category.ID} label={category.Name} value={category.ID}/>
    )});`

Comment: Sorry, Editing timed out on that comment: When modifying `pickerItems` arrow function to look like this: {return( <Picker.Item ... />) } or this: (<Picker.Item ... />) the same error persists, I should also mention that I actually removed all of the render function for DiscoverSearch with the exception of some <Text> in a <View> and I still got the same error shown above.

Comment: Instead of calling your ListHeaderCreate function and passing the value, try just passing the function itself. ```ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderCreate}``` instead of ```ListHeaderCreate()```.

Comment: OH MY GOSH. I was stuck on that for two hours. That fixed it. So when the console says it's expecting a class/funciton, it really means, I want the function, not the invocation of said function. Do you know why React is like that?

Comment: Yeah if it is expecting a class/function, you should give it a class/function. Now if the invocation of a function returns a new function (Like in Higher Order Components) that would be okay. This has to do with React's Prop-Type system which you can learn about here: [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue here was with a mismatch in React Prop-Types. [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

The `VirtualizedList` component is expecting a class or a function, so passing it a function that evaluates a React Class will give it an object, and this throws an error.

The solution is to pass in the function itself like so:

```
ListHeaderComponent={ ListHeaderCreate }
```